# React) I want to know how to load the iframe(youtube) of the card when clicking on the card in the card list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I want to know how to load the iframe(youtube) of the card when clicking on the card in the card list.
Currently, when one card is clicked, an iframe is displayed as many as the number of cards.

The current logic is calling the api to get the card list. And when one card is pressed, it calls the api to get the video link with the id of the card.

```
<ItemList>
    {data.results.map((e) => (
        <Item key={e.id}>
          <img
            src={e.poster_path}
            alt={e.title}
            onClick={() => {
                onClickVideo(e.id) // Put the video link on click in useState.(videoUrl)
            }}
          />
          {videoUrl && (
            <iframe src={`${videoUrl}`} width="300" height="200"></iframe>
          )}
        </Item>
      ))}
  </ItemList>
```

And is it possible to set the iframe position?

Comment: Your question is about changing the state for one element, not about an iframe really. Do you want to show one video at a time or possibly show multiple at once?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I want one to show. For example, I want the YouTube iframe of 'a' to be displayed when the card 'a' is clicked.

Comment: `videoUrl === videoUrlOfThatCard && ( <iframe ...`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Thank you. I succeeded in showing only one.
But is it possible to handle it so that the iframe is on top? I want to do dim processing.

Comment: Move it out of the list then and create a modal

Answer (score 0):

You are setting "videoUrl" in onCLickVideo function that is why when its value is set all iframes in all cards rendered. So you need to put only iframe in your code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).